# Why does a Kotlin sequence perform so bad on small number of elements?

Tags: kotlin

I've tried to compare the performance of a Kotlin sequence against a Kotlin collection: [Kotlin Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/CW58MYdnW) and my expectation was that the sequence will outperform the collection each and every time, but it didn't for the smallest number of elements 10, here are my results:

```
==============================
Size 10
Lista: 62835 ns
Sekvenca: 7050134 ns
==============================

==============================
Size 100
Lista: 96139 ns
Sekvenca: 10376 ns
==============================

==============================
Size 1000
Lista: 702532 ns
Sekvenca: 9689 ns
==============================

==============================
Size 10000
Lista: 2598859 ns
Sekvenca: 26116 ns
==============================

==============================
Size 100000
Lista: 11004099 ns
Sekvenca: 45011 ns
==============================

==============================
Size 1000000
Lista: 623017128 ns
Sekvenca: 55156 ns
==============================
```

I am confused as to why that is, could someone elaborate? Because next time I run it I added yet another size of 5, but this time the size of 10 showed results in favor of the sequence, is this perhaps some kind of bug?

Comment: Playground should have an engine that limits the allocation of resources. If you want to test it, deploy on your own machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with list size, sequence just has a bit larger overhead.

When you're performing the first loop jvm has to load classes required for sequence into memory. You can alter your playground by adding list of size 1 first and it will shorten the time of size 10 calculations dramatically.

Comment: Interesting, does that mean if I'm working with just one big sequence that the equivalent collection will perform better until a certain size?

Comment: It's not just about loading classes; it also has to construct instances of all the objects needed to represent and implement the pipeline processing that sequence.  So you have memory and CPU overhead in creating those objects (constant for a given pipeline), and then CPU overhead in using them to run the pipeline (linear in the sequence size).  So it's generally recommended not to bother with a sequence/stream unless you're likely to have very big structures (thousands of elements); otherwise, the overhead isn't likely to be significantly less than that of direct intermediate structures.

Comment: @ulrich201 not necessarily, sequence will only have a one time delay for the first time you ever call it within your program. You can put your loop in a loop in your playground and you'll see subsequent calls are always fast.

Answer (score 7):

This is what your results look like on a log-log chart:

[image: urlich201 Benchmark: List vs. Sequence]

Instead of the expected two straight lines, we get pretty much nonsensical curves. For example, it appears that processing a sequence of 10 items is 200 times more expensive than processing 100,000 items.

I improved your benchmark by applying some basics of microbenchmarking on the JVM, like allowing for warmup and not ignoring the result of the computation:

```
val size = 10
val warmupIterations = 100_000
val measureIterations = 100_000
val collection = List(size) { Weather((-10..10).shuffled().first()) }
val sequence = collection.asSequence()

var controlSum = 0L

fun main() {
    val (a, b) = benchmark(warmupIterations)
    println("Warmed up: $a $b")

    val (listInNanos, sequenceInNanos) = benchmark(measureIterations)

    println("Control sum: $controlSum")
    println("size $size")
    println("list %.0f sequence %.0f".format(listInNanos, sequenceInNanos))
}

private fun benchmark(iterations: Int): Pair<Double, Double> {
    val listInNanos = (1..iterations).map {
        measureNanoTime {
            controlSum += listApi(collection)
        }
    }.average()

    val sequenceInNanos = (1..iterations).map {
        measureNanoTime {
            controlSum += sequencApi(sequence)
        }
    }.average()
    return Pair(listInNanos, sequenceInNanos)
}

private fun sequencApi(sequence: Sequence<Weather>): Int {
    return (sequence
            .map { it.temperature }
            .filter { it % 2 == 0 }
            .firstOrNull { it < 0 }) ?: -1
}

private fun listApi(collection: List<Weather>): Int {
    return (collection
            .map { it.temperature }
            .filter { it % 2 == 0 }
            .firstOrNull { it < 0 }) ?: -1
}
```

These are my results:

[image: mtopolnik Benchmark: List vs. Sequence]

Compared to your results, the cost of processing 10 items is now 100 times smaller with Collection API and 1,000,000 times smaller with the Sequence API.

Main conclusion: for your use case, `Sequence` processing is cheaper than `Collection` processing across the board.

Comment: I think the test can be improved and doesn't clearly show which is faster. When using a Sequence, `.firstOrNull` is terminating with the first result found. Sequences are lazy. A collection executes all records against each method in order before going to the next method (`map`, then `filter`, and lastly `firstOrNull`). A Sequence may not iterate over the whole set. This is the case with using `firstOrNull`, which executes almost immediately, without going thru the whole list. A better test to measure performance is to iterate the whole list by terminating with something like `toList`.

Comment: Indeed this question is not about comparing sequences with collections in general, it is focuses on one specific construction it's testing, which is why OP states they expected the sequence to be faster in every case. The answer confirms that this expectation was correct.

Comment: Agree, just adding some context as to why it is faster. In general it is faster, but the setup for this test exits early instead of executing against every item like the List/collection does.